# node js mongoose find an field increment

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nodes

I have saved my data in MongoDB using mongoose. Now I want to get the 'quantity' field in cart and increment by 1.

Note : If you have better way to do it, Please help.

here is how the MongoDB Atlas collection looks like

[image]

Here is how iam doing it :

```
const User = require("../models/User");

exports.updateQuantity = async (req, res) => {
try {
const { userId } = req.body;
if (!userId) {
  res.json("All fields are required");
  }

let result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  userId,
  {
    $inc: {
      "cart.$[inner].newProduct.quantity": 1,
    },
  },
  {
    new: true,
  }
);

res.send({
  success: true,
  message: "Product has been incremented",
  result: result,
 });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return res.status(500).json({
  success: false,
  message: "Something went wrong",
 });
}
};
```

Getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You doing good, actually you need to get the right object since you are working in an array.
I see the cart could have multiple product so you need to find the right product by its id

Pass to your query another parameter to match the right object like this :

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id : userId, "cart.userId" : userId, "cart.newProduct._id" : productId })
```

Than you can increment by adding

```
$inc: {
  "cart.newProduct.quantity": 1,
},
```

Maybe you won't have to put the `"cart.userId" : userId` in the filter if there aren't other userId
Hope it works !